# Sharp triangles appearing in interpolated height map

Tags: c++, opengl

As a project, I have to generate a random NxN rough terrain in modern opengl.  For this, I use a height map, rendering each 2xN row with triangle strip.
Shaders are basic, specifying a shade of yellow corresponding to the height(so I can see the bends; I have a top-down camera).  Interpolation is on, but for some reason, weird sharp triangular shapes get rendered.
1)  They always appear on the right side of the screen.
2)  They are bigger than the unit triangle I render.

eg: I don't have the reputation to post images, so...

8x8 http://imgbox.com/flC187WW

128x128 http://i.imgbox.com/f1ebrk0V.png

And here's the code:

```
    void drawMeshRow(int rno, float oy) {
        GLfloat meshVert[MESHSIZE * 2 * 3];
        for(int i = 0; i < 2 * MESHSIZE; ++i) {
            meshVert[3*i] = (i/2)*(2.0/(MESHSIZE-1)) - 1;
            if(i & 1) {
                meshVert[3*i + 1] = oy;
                meshVert[3*i + 2] = heightMap[rno][i/2];
            } 
            else {
               meshVert[3*i + 1] = oy + (2.0/(MESHSIZE-1));
               meshVert[3*i + 2] = heightMap[rno + 1][i/2];
            }
        }
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * 3 * MESHSIZE * sizeof(GLfloat), meshVert, GL_STREAM_DRAW); 
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, MESHSIZE * 2 * 3);
    }
    void drawMesh() {
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshBuff);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
        for(int i = 0; i < MESHSIZE - 1; ++i) 
            drawMeshRow(i, (2.0 / (MESHSIZE - 1)) * i - 1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }
```

drawMesh is called each iteration of the main loop.

Shaders:

Vertex shader

```
    #version 330 core
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
    smooth out float height;
    void main() {
        gl_Position.xyz = pos;
        height = pos.z;
        gl_Position.w = 1.0;
    }
```

Fragment Shader

```
    #version 330 core
    out vec3 pcolor;
    smooth in float height;
    void main() {
        pcolor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, height);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the wrong count to `glDrawArrays()`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, MESHSIZE * 2 * 3);
```

The last argument is the vertex count, while the value you pass is the total number of coordinates. The correct call is:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, MESHSIZE * 2);
```